# Handler of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException doesn't get called

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, .net-4.6

I'm trying to set up my .net application in such a way, an unhandled exception is always logged somewhere. My understanding is two handlers needs to be set for this, `Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException` for UI threads (followed by `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)`) and the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` for non-UI threads. I do so in my application's `Sub Main()`, and the `Application.ThreadException`-Handler is actually working, but I can't figure out, how to get the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`-Handler to work (or why isn't it working).

My test code is like this:

```
Private Sub ThreadTask(ByVal StateObj As Object)
        Throw New Exception("Unhandled Exception")
End Sub

Public Sub CauseException()
    Dim StObj As New ThreadParamsObj
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf ThreadTask, StObj)
End Sub
```

If I try it in a minimalistic test application (a Form with a single Button, the `AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhandledExceptionHandler` is called in `Form1_Load`) -- it works as expected, a `MsgBox` is shown etc. But in the "real" application it doesn't work.

What could prevent the event from firing or the handler from handling it?

**The answer is:** both `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open` and `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.Open` (and maybe other DbConnections) in **.net 3.5**, upgrading to to **.net 4.6.1** fixes the issue.

Comment: You are saying you don't like UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException.  You should not like it.  Always favor UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException so *all* exceptions are reported through your appdomain event handler.  Gets rid of the useless and dangerous exception dialog *and* does not cripple the debugger.

Comment: I never said I don't like it. BTW, additional question: atm exceptions caught by `Application.ThreadException`-Handler don't cause crash to desktop, while those caught by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`-Handler do.
What happens, if I set `UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException` -- will the application crash after processing the UI Thread exception in the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`-Handler?

Comment: The question says so, maybe the author doesn't yet know it :)  Yes.